# Adding Variables using batch

Tags: batch-file, variables, echo

For my AP Physics 2 project we have to create something that can calculate the equations for resistors and capacitors, I'm having problems with having the variables actually add up to a complete number rather than just being 2+4+4 as an output.

Below is my code so far:

```
@echo off
 echo Do you want Resitors, or Capacitors.
 echo Type R or C when prompted. 
    set /p input0=Enter:
    if %input0% equ R goto R1
    if %input0% equ C goto C1
    goto startup
    echo Press any key to continue. 
    pause>nul


    :R1
    cls
    echo Do you want Series or Parallel?
    echo Type S or P when prompted.
        set /p input1=Enter:
        if %input1% equ S goto S1
        if %input1% equ P goto P1
        goto Startup
        echo Press any key to continue.
        pause>nul

        :S1
        cls
        echo What are your 3 values?
            set /p input2=Enter:
        echo.
            set /p input3=Enter:
        echo.
            set /p input4=Enter: 
        echo.
        set /p "Answer=%input2%+%input3%+%input4%"
        echo %Answer%
        goto Startup
        echo Press any key to continue.
        pause>nul

        :P1
        cls
        echo What are your 3 values?
            set /p input5=Enter:
        echo.
            set /p input6=Enter:
        echo.
            set /p input7=Enter:
        echo.
            set /a "Answer=(1/((1/%input6%)+(1/%input5%)+(1/%input7%)))"
        echo %Answer%
        goto Startup
        echo Press any key to continue.
        pause>nul
```

Comment: Mainly this is the problem:                                                                                           set /p "Answer=%input2%+%input3%+%input4%                                    
echo %Answer%                                                                                                                            And if I try changing it to set /a it doesn't work, just crashes after they define their variables.

Comment: You can only `goto Startup` if there is a `:Startup`, it should be `set /a` for your arithmetic operations, you should use `==` for string comparisons, and it's better to enclose both sides of a comparison in matching double quotes. Comparisons are case sensitive too so try this syntax; `if /I "%input1%"=="S" goto S1 ` instead. With arithmetic you don't need to include the `%` characters with your variable names; `set /a Answer=input2+input3+input4`.

Comment: More importantly Judge, batch arithmetic only works with 32 bit signed integers, fractional results will be rounded down to the nearest whole integer, It would not be feasible to use cmd scripting alone, choose a scripting language which can can perform accurate decimal calculations, perhaps powershell.